# PHP Curl Response

Tags: php, curl, post

I am currently working with an API for a little project of mine that will only accept POST requests, however no matter what I seem to do I cannot get a response out of it, I have tried echoing the response, I have tried returning it, I have tried using print_r and nothing works. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php

$applicationPass = $_GET['appPass'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

if ($applicationPass == "abc123"){
//

$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true, 
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.minergate.com/1.0/auth/login/',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'email' => urlencode($_GET['email']),
    'password' => urlencode($_GET['password'])
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
echo $resp;
//
}else{
    die();
}

?>
```

Here is my updated code, I get a little bit of a different response with their new API that took forever to find.

```
<?php

$applicationPass = $_GET['appPass'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

if ($applicationPass == "abc123"){
//

$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true, 
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://minergate.com/api/2.2/auth/login',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0',
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'email: ' . $email,
        'password: ' . $password
    )),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'email' => urlencode($email),
    'password' => urlencode($password)
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
echo $resp;
//
}else{
    die();
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you look at [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) ? What's the response of `print_r` / `var_dump` ?

Comment: run the curl code inside an if(isset($_POST['some_var'])) conditional

Comment: `if ($applicationPass = "abc123"){` should really be `if ($applicationPass == "abc123"){`

Comment: Atleast for me, `www.api.minergate.com` doesn't resolve - make sure you're using the correct url (probably just `api.minergate.com`?) - This is one of the errors `curl_error` would have told you about.

Comment: @ccKep that was part of the issue, now when i run the code I get the following error from their API: {"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"GET is not allowed"}

Comment: Try using `CURLOPT_POST => true` instead of `CURLOPT_POST => 1`, the php docs state that it should be a boolean.

Comment: It seems as though the API itself is severely broken. I fixed the issue by replacing CURLOPT_POST => 1 with CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST' and by sending a JSON body along with the request (as [the documentation](https://github.com/MinerGate/minergate-api#login) states), but the API then complained about the absence of the "user email" : `{"error":"MissingEmail","argument":"email","message":"User email must be specified."}`

Comment: Just updated with the new endpoint, however I get this now instead: {"error":"InvalidEmail","argument":"email","message":"User email is invalid."}

Comment: Try it without urlencoding the email and password. I couldn't find any documentation for the 2.2 version of the API, but if I suggest removing the `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER...` call from the `curl_setopt_array` array.

Comment: warning, you're vulnerable to timing attacks on line 7 (both files), so hackers can extract the password. use hash_equals instead